# Validation of Video file(from Youtube) in webpage using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to validate if a Video is present and playing or not in the Webpage when the page is opened using selenium?

Comment: you can check it with it video play time

Comment: You cannot perform image or video validation using selenium.